# Django models : pick up existing players for a team in admin

Tags: django, django-models

I need help defining models in Django. What I need is :

- players,
- and teams.

In terms of relationships :

- 1 player can only be a member in one team (or no team) at a time,
- and (obviously) teams can only include existing players.

So I suppose that there should be a One-to-many relationship from teams to players. What I would like to have in the admin side of Django is :

1) when creating/editing a player : a drop-down list to pick up a team,

2) and when creating/editing a team, the ability to create a list of players from an existing list ("Add" from a drop-down, for instance).

While 1) is automatic when adding a ForeignKey to teams in the model for players, I don't know how to achieve 2).

Say my models are :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name

class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to add another table to write your team player info to it.

For editing, my guess is that you are looking for something like [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player_name


class TeamPlayer(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player.player_name
```

admin.py

```
class TeamPlayerAdminInline(admin.TabularInlin):
    model = TeamPlayer


@admin.register(Team)
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['team_name']
    inlines = [TeamPlayerAdminInline]


@admin.register(Player)
class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin);
    list_display = ['player_name']
    inlines = [TeamPlayerAdminInline]
```

Comment: With the models as I copied them in my question, or with a ForeignKey somewhere ?

Comment: i've added models.py file

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this doesn't do what I need. With admin.TabularInline I can create new players from within a Team's profile, but what I need is to pick players from the list of existing players.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood you a bit... btw. this is all done without testing, but this should be it. please check new edit

Comment: In terms of UI, that's exactly what I wanted. Now the only problem left is that if I edit the team in a player's profile, it doesn't get updated in the team's profile, and vice versa.

Comment: ouh, sorry. i haven't removed the foreign key from Player :D

Comment: Added inlines to `PlayerAdmin` also. This way you can actually see all the player's past teams if you are writing transfers and stuff like that.